# Onclick Add/Remove specific string from textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, contact-form-7

I've got a form with some selects that auto populate a sentence in a textarea, however, I wan't to be able to then remove the sentence it has added to the textarea if they click it again.

I would just clear the entire textarea value but that wouldn't work as they may have clicked 2 prefills and I only want to remove the specific content added by the prefill they're clicking.

```
    var contactTextarea = jQuery('.form-contents .ori-textarea .query-textarea-ori');

    jQuery( "#query-telcoedge" ).click(function() {
        prefill = jQuery(this).attr('rel');

        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){

        } else {
            contactTextarea.val(contactTextarea.val() + prefill + '\n');
        }

        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the text, you can use `.replace`.

This will remove only the first match, so if the user copies your text so it appears twice, only the first will be removed.  To remove all you can use `.replaceAll`. [(not IE11)](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll)

If the text has been changed by the user, it won't remove it

```
if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    contactTextarea.val(contactTextarea.val().replace(prefill + '\n', ""));
} else ...
```